# Rewrite static html to dynamic php error bad flag delimiters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Having gone through some suggestions about rewriting static url to php url i have hit snag trying to redirect    http://www.example.com/clothing to http://www.example.com/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=999
using this rule

```
RewriteRule ^clothing/index.html index.php?main_page=index&cPath=999 [L]
```

I keep getting

```
rewriterule: bad flag delimiter
```

even after changing/adding / and \ to the rule.

This is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# From Ultimate SEO URLs
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$ index\.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=&%   {QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ index\.php?main_page=index&cPath=&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=index&manufacturers_id=&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pi-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pr-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=product_reviews&  products_id=&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pri-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=product_reviews_info&products_id=&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-ezp-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=page&id=&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

# All other pages
# Don't rewrite real files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index\.php?main_page=&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```